# コンポーネント化しようとするとエラーが発生する

Tags: reactjs

下記のサイトを参考にしながら、React×Typscriptでプロフィールサイトを作成しています。
Skills.tsx内の `<Box display='flex' justifyContent='center' p={1} >` 以下をコンポーネント化したく、Technic．tsxを作成し、色々調べて実装したのですが、エラー表示が出て、これ以上積んでわからない状態です。
何方かアドバイスをお願いします。

[スキル一覧（Skills）を作成 | React × TypeScriptで作ったポートフォリオサイトをGitHub Pagesで公開してみる](https://qiita.com/kazama1209/items/868c09393007cc9b234f#%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AD%E3%83%AB%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7skills%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90)

---

※下記のソースコードは引用テキストを雛形として参考にし、装飾等はサイトを検索して、カスタムをしています。

**App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import MyAvatar from './components/MyAvatar';
import About from './components/About';
import Skills from './components/Skills';
import Technic from './components/Technic';
※エラー文'./components/Technic' またはそれに対応する型宣言が見つかりません。

const App: React.FC = () =>  {
  return (
    <>
    <section>
    <Navbar/>
    </section>
    <section>
    <MyAvatar />
    </section>
    <section id='about'>
    <About />
    </section>
    <section id='skills'>
    <Skills />
    </section>
    <section id='Technic'>
    <Technic />
    </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Skills.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
// import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
// import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import './Skills.module.scss';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: 730,
    maxWidth: '100%',  
  },
});

const Skills: React.FC = () => {

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    　<>
    <Box p={2}>
      <Box display='flex' justifyContent='center' p={1} >
        <Typography variant='h5' >
          Skills
        </Typography>
      </Box>


※　コンポーネント化（Tecnic.tsx)したい箇所
 {/* <Box display='flex' justifyContent='center' p={1} >
        <Card className={classes.root}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="h6">
            Programming language
            </Typography>
            <Typography color="textSecondary">
              Ruby / JavaScript / TypeScript
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Box>
      <Box display='flex' justifyContent='center' p={1} >
        <Card className={classes.root}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="h6">
            Framework　
            </Typography>
            <Typography color="textSecondary">
              Ruby on Rails  / React
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Box>
      <Box display='flex' justifyContent='center' p={1} >
        <Card className={classes.root}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="h6">
            Database
              </Typography>
              <Typography color="textSecondary">
                MySQL / PostgreSQL
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Box>
        <Box display='flex' justifyContent='center' p={1} >
          <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography variant="h6">
                AWS
              </Typography>
              <Typography color="textSecondary">
                EC2 / ECS / ECR / Lambda / SQS / SNS / Elastic Beanstalk / S3 / Cloud9 / CloudWatch / CloudFormation / RDS / Route53
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Box> */}
※　コンポーネント化（Tecnic.tsx)したい箇所（ここまで）

      </Box>
    </>
  );
}

export default Skills;
```

**※ コンポーネント化 (Tecnic.tsx) したファイル**

```
import React from "react";
import Box from '@material-ui/core/Box';
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
      width: 730,
      maxWidth: '100%',  
    },
  });

  const Technic: React.FC = () => {
　　　　　※エラー文　：　'Technic' が宣言されていますが、その値が読み取られることはありません。
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <>
    <Box p={2}>
<      Box display='flex' justifyContent='center' p={1} >
        <Card className={classes.root}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="h6">
            Programming language
            </Typography>
            <Typography color="textSecondary">
              Ruby / JavaScript / TypeScript
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Box>
      <Box display='flex' justifyContent='center' p={1} >
        <Card className={classes.root}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="h6">
            Framework　
            </Typography>
            <Typography color="textSecondary">
              Ruby on Rails  / React
            </Typography>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
      </Box>
      <Box display='flex' justifyContent='center' p={1} >
        <Card className={classes.root}>
          <CardContent>
            <Typography variant="h6">
            Database
              </Typography>
              <Typography color="textSecondary">
                MySQL / PostgreSQL
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Box>
        <Box display='flex' justifyContent='center' p={1} >
          <Card className={classes.root}>
            <CardContent>
              <Typography variant="h6">
                AWS
              </Typography>
              <Typography color="textSecondary">
                EC2 / ECS / ECR / Lambda / SQS / SNS / Elastic Beanstalk / S3 / Cloud9 / CloudWatch / CloudFormation / RDS / Route53
              </Typography>
            </CardContent>
          </Card>
        </Box>
    </Box>

      </>
  );
}

export default Box;
```

Comment: 手元で試して確認してないのでコメントしますが、エラーの通りで`Tecnic.tsx`で `export default Box;` されてて`const Technic`は使用されてないようです。**これに関しては** `export default Technic;`に直せば良さそうな気がします。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。早速、訂正してみます。